# Sort MATCH AGAINST by different variable in database?

Tags: php, sql, match, against

So I want to be able to change how results of a search query are listed.  The top (sort by relevance) works, but when I try to order by a different variable in the same database, it doesn't work.  Any suggestions?  Please and thanks.

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['sortby']) or $qsortby=="relevance")
{
    $result = 
    "SELECT *,
        MATCH (title, keywords) AGAINST ('+".$q."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,
        MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+".$q."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS title_relevance
        FROM designs
        WHERE MATCH (title, keywords) AGAINST ('".$q."')
        ORDER BY title_relevance DESC, relevance DESC";
 }
        else
        {
        $result = 
    "SELECT *,
            MATCH (title, keywords) AGAINST ('+".$q."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,
        FROM designs
        WHERE MATCH (title, keywords) AGAINST ('".$q."')
        ORDER BY rating DESC";
        }
```

Comment: Where does `$q` come into play; that wouldn't be mistaken for `$qsortby`, would it?

Comment: $q is my search query